# Fixed height Bootstrap card with vertically-scrollable card-text

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I achieve a **fixed height** bootstrap 4 card that has a vertically-scrollable **card-text** portion?

```
<div class="card" style="height:300px">        <-- non scrollable
    <div class="card-body">                    <-- non scrollable
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5> <-- non scrollable
        <p class="card-text">This portion and only this portion will have a very long text so much so that the vertical scroll bar may appear when required.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to wrap the `.card-text` with a scrollable container. Then set the scrollable container `overflow-y: auto;`.

Don't forget to set the `height` for scrollable container too. Scroll bar will not appear if the `height` is auto as default.

https://codepen.io/blackcityhenry/pen/LXOOgW

Answer (score 3):

you need to apply this css

```
**wrap this**
.card-text { height: 42px; overflow-x: scroll; width: 100%; }

.card-text p { width: 650px; word-break: break-word; }
```

Answer (score 0):

### In css code for horizontal scroll

```html
<style>
 .card-text { height: 42px; overflow-x: scroll; width: 100%; }
    
 .card-text p { width: 650px; word-break: break-word; }
</style>
```

### In css code for vertical scroll

```css
<style>
 .card-text { height: 42px; overflow-y: scroll; width: 100%; }
    
 .card-text p { width: 650px; word-break: break-word; }
</style>
```

### In html - for horizontal scroll / vertical scroll

```html
<div class="card" style="height:300px">        
    <div class="card-body">                    
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5> 
        <p class="card-text">This portion and only this portion will have a very long text so much so that the vertical scroll bar may appear when required.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add  `style="overflow-y: scroll;height:auto;max-height:SOME-MAX-HEIGHTpx;"` to the container which needs to be vertically scrollable